# How to count depending on 2 conditions

Tags: r

I look at the "flights" table from the `library(nycflights13)`package. I try to create a table from it that contains the **number of flights per carrier per airport of origin**. My initial idea was to count the number of each airline for each airport of origin.

So the table could look like this:

```
number of flights / carrier / origin
200-AA-JFK
147-AA-ALM (because airlines could have flown off from different airports)
etc...
```

Frankly, I have no idea how to approach this problem in terms of coding. I started with this simple two-liner:

```
flights %>%
  count(carrier)
```

It shows me the count of each airline. Is it somehow possible to add another count criterion, such as origin, so that the function would count the **number of airlines for each origin**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to `group_by` and then take the `sum` of 'flights'

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)
flights %>% 
  group_by(origin, carrier) %>%
  summarise(nflights = sum(flight), count = n())
```

---

If we don't need the `sum` of 'flight', then use `count` with multiple columns

```
flights %>%
   count(origin, carrier)
```

Comment: What does the sum(flight) do? It simply adds up the flight numbers, right? So leaving it out and just using the count = n() argument would show the number of flights / airline / airport, or?

Comment: @shymilk  Yes, you are right.  I was not sure what you really wanted.  So, I used `sum`, the `n()` would give the frequency i.e. number of rows for each group, which is basically what the `count(origin, carrier)` gives

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `data.table` package and the following command

```
flights[, .N, .(origin, carrier)]
```